# Is Code first and Database first hybrid possible in same project?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

I am developing my site with MVC4 with entity framework (database first approach).

I have almost complete half of my project. The issue I am facing now is there are lots of changes in database structure. I tried, but couldn't able to tackle all the db structural change with code dynamically.

So, now just wondering, is it possible to develop project with both code and db first, hybrid approach (I have very less knowledge regarding code first approach).

Any Help or Suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You could do code first from the database

Comment: @Pawel : It will be gr8, if you could explain a bit.

Comment: MSDN: [Code First to an Existing Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx)